# Why doesn't Newton-Raphson work for these type of functions?

Tags: roots, newton-raphson

Suppose that for $f(x)$, $\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=3x$. If I wanted to find a root for $f$ using the Newton-Raphson method I have the formula $x_{n+1} = x_{n} - \frac{f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})} = x_{n} - 3x_{n} = -2x_{n}$ but trying it out it just oscillates between numbers and doesn't give a concrete result. Why does this happen?

Comment: For reference, $f(x)=Ax^{1/3}$ has the desired property. Also, the map $x_{n+1}\mapsto -2x_n$ doesn’t just oscillate: it grows larger and larger without bound.

Comment: How does that function explain why the map keeps growing larger?

Comment: The iteration is repeated multiplication by $-2$, which grows without bound. (E.g., $1\mapsto -2\mapsto 4\mapsto \cdots$.)

Comment: If you put a marble in a bowl, it will roll to the center. You can push it away, but it will just roll back. Now turn the bowl over. If the outside of the bowl follows the same geometry as the inside, there is a spot on the top where the marble will stay - if you get it absolutely right there. But if it is even slightly off, the marble will roll away for the equilibrium point instead of towards it. That is what is happening here. For a kit of functions, the root is a stable equilibrium of N.-R., but there is no guarantee. For this one, it is an unstable equilibrium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
$$ \text{The Newton-Raphson iterations are shown for the function}   \ y \ = \ 2.3·x^{1/3} \ \   $$ $$ \text{with an initial "guess"}   \ x_0 \ = \ 8 \ \ . \  \text{ (Note that the horizontal scale is greatly compressed.) } $$

The "correction term" you've given can be treated as a differential equation which yields $$  \frac{y}{dy/dx} \ \ = \ \ 3x \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \frac{dy}{y} \ \ = \ \ \frac13 \ \frac{dx}{x} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ln y \ \ = \ \ \frac13  \ln x \ \ + \ \ C \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ \ = \ \ A·x^{1/3} \ \ . $$

So your example is some multiple of a cube-root function, which has *very* shallow slope over most of its curve.  Since the Newton-Raphson method uses $  \ x-$intercepts of tangent lines to the function curve as "iterates" to the zero, unless our choice for $ \ x_0 \ $ is "quite close" to the zero of this function, the intercept of the tangent line at $ \ x_0 \ $ will be *very* far from the zero we are seeking.  If $ \ x_1 \ $ lies on the opposite side of that zero from $ \ x_0 \  \ , \ $ we are now on the part of the curve with slope of opposite sign.  This will set up an "oscillation" around the zero for the successive iterations, with no likelihood of convergence. (Here we have a "geometrically increasing" oscillation, as described in the comments above.)

In the "correction terms", we really want to see $ \ \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \ = \ C·x_n \ \  $  with $ \ |C| \ << \ 1 \ \ $ in order to have rapid convergence.

Newton-Raphson is not a "universal" method and quite a lot has been written on the various ways it can fail to converge.  As is apparent, there are types of functions and "function behavior" in the neighborhood of zeroes  for which this method cannot be recommended.

Comment: Another sign of how strange Newton-Raphson can be at times is to ask which initial seeds converge to which root (if any), and how fast if so. This kind of thinking gives rise to the beautiful complexity of [Newton fractals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal).